# How to remove obsolete/orphaned items from TaxonomyHiddenList

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

**Explanation of environment:** I am running SharePoint 2010 SP1, December CU's.  I have a list item which has a taxonomy column.  As expected, if a term (e.g. “foo”) is deleted from the term store, users no longer see “foo” as an option for new items, but the term remains on previous items because “foo” is not deleted from the TaxonomyHiddenList by the Taxonomy Update Scheduler job.

**Problem:**
This presents problems with search because if “foo” is deleted, we don’t want anyone to ever know “foo” existed anywhere on our site.

**Desired Behavior:**
In addition to updating current items, I would like orphaned terms to be deleted from the TaxonomyHiddenList

**Proposed Solution:**
Write a custom timer job to iterate through all terms and delete any orphaned items from the TaxonomyHiddenList

**Question:**
Is this a viable solution?  Am I missing something?  Is there a more elegant way to handle this than manhandling the TaxonomyHiddenList?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomysession.synchiddenlist.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rikard, but that method only updates the list.  It does not remove old terms from the hidden list.

Comment: Allright, interesting.
Then I would say that the most viable solution is as you propose; to write a timer job to clean up the list at a regular interval.